# openlayers3 how to always enable freehand draw

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In OpenLayers3 v3.5, how do you always enable freehand draw?  The default for enabling freehand draw is done through the `freehandCondition` property of `ol.interaction.Draw`, which is currently set to the shift key by default.

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: drawLayer.getSource(),
  type: 'LineString',
  freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly
});
```

But I dont want that.  I dont want the shift key to be pressed to enable freehand.  I want freehand to be enabled by click-and-drag without any key modifiers.

I've tried:

`freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.always`

`freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.click`

`freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.noModifierKeys`

But none of these work.

You may wonder that by doing this would pan the map, but I've already disabled panning by changing my default interactions so that `dragPan: false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed in [the documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.interaction.Draw.html), the `condition` parameter for the `ol.interaction.Draw`. It conflicts with `freehandCondition`.

It should be like below (tested)

```
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
  source: drawLayer.getSource(),
  type: 'LineString',
   condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
   freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.noModifierKeys
});
```

Look at [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdf08y9x/) for a demo.

I may missed a better option. You may also need to try with other conditions if the behaviour is not exactly the expected one.

Comment: The way you did is quite nice, but we still need to double click in order to finish the sketch. Is there a way to start drawing freehand on mouse down, and finish drawing on mouse up?