# openlayers3 how to always enable freehand draw and drag

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to do the free hand draw like this post:
[openlayers3 how to always enable freehand draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420416/openlayers3-how-to-always-enable-freehand-draw)

But when i use with interaction dragPan is true it's doesn't keep the draw

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: layers,
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
  dragPan: false
  }),
  view: new ol.View({
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2
  })
});
```

My example :https://jsfiddle.net/tdf08y9x/12/

It's maybe openlayers bug.

Thanks

Comment: There was indeed a bug, which is now fixed on master, and the fix will be in the v3.15.0 release. See http://jsfiddle.net/tdf08y9x/24/ for an updated version of your JSFiddle. The fix came with https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/5071.

Comment: Oky thanks, meanwhile i do some trick for alternative solution : https://jsfiddle.net/tdf08y9x/25/